# Python and CGI: Display errors in browser instead of downloading file

Tags: python, python-3.x, cgi

I'm practicing with using Python 3 and CGI to display pages in the browser. I'm running into an issue that I can't seem to figure out though.

There is an error somewhere in my python code I assume but I don't know of a way to figure out what it is.

Basically when I try to run the script the browser wants to download the python file instead. When I comment out a block of code that I suspect is causing the error, it display everything fine.

I have `cgitb.enable()` imported and included in the file but that's not displaying anything for this error.

Is there a way to see any python errors in the browser? Or at least be able to log the error to a text file that I can go and look at?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use Sentry - https://www.getsentry.com/welcome/

It will give you the great interface for errors. You can use it for free.

Note: I am not affiliated with them, I just use that happily for our own solutions.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it out!